# Node process.env variable in eval() function gives different result

Tags: javascript, node.js, kubernetes, eval, server-side-rendering

I have a react app running in node with serverside rendering.
The following environment variable is set to `test` through kubernetes in my test environment: `process.env.NODE_ENV`.

When I run the following two commands they give different results. I expect the value to always be `test`.

```
log.debug(process.env.NODE_ENV) // logs development
log.debug(eval('process.env.NODE_ENV')) // logs test
```

Somehow, it looks like the variable is first interpreted as `development` (Which can happen in my code if it is undefined), but it is somehow interpreted correctly to `test` by the `eval()` function.

What can cause node to interpret the value differently between the two expressions?

EDIT: Added kubernetes yaml config.
The ${} variables are replaced by Azure DevOps during the release process.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: config
  namespace: ${KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE}
data:
  NODE_ENV: ${NODE_ENV}
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ${SERVICE_NAME}
spec:
  selector:
    app: ${SERVICE_NAME}
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 3000

  loadBalancerIP: ${IP_NUMBER}
  type: LoadBalancer


---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ${SERVICE_NAME}
  labels:
    app: ${SERVICE_NAME}
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ${SERVICE_NAME}

  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ${SERVICE_NAME}
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ${SERVICE_NAME}
        image: {IMAGE_PATH}/${IMAGE_REPO}:${BUILD_NUMBER}
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 3000
          protocol: TCP
        resources: 
          limits:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 1024Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 1024Mi
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: config

      imagePullSecrets: 
      - name: ${IMAGEPULLSECRETNAME}
```

Comment: All due respect, I find it impossible to believe that those two statements, one right after another like that, with the standard `process` object and the standard `eval` function, can produce different results. Is this **literally** your code? If so, you'll need to post a [mcve] with all necessary config files (but again: the bare minimum) to allow someone else to replicate it, because it would be **very**, **very** weird. (But hey, weird things do happen.)

Comment: By the way you formulated your question, seems to me you aren't a begginer in programming. If I'm correct, you should know that what you're proposing is that you found a bug in Node or in V8 engine. This is a big claim. Big claims need big proofs. So in order for us to help you you really need to show the code that produced this and a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I cannot share the entire codebase, as this is a work project. I can of course share edited versions of config files, but I honestly don't know where to begin, as the codebase is rather large, and a lot of things could influence this. I'll start by adding the kubernets config. If you have any suggestions as to specific configs I need to add, please do tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seem to have found the cause of the issue.
We use webpack for bundling (which I maybe should have mentioned), and in the server code webpack has outputted, I see that it has resolved `process.env.NODE_ENV` to a static value, but it doesn't do the same for `eval(process.env.NODE_ENV)`.
Seems my post was unecessary, but I hope it might help someone in the future.

Comment: Self-answers are welcome on SO. Chances for the question to be answered weren't great because you didn't mention that you use Webpack in the first place.